# Android: How to get the fragment id (0,1,2...)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Well, im working on a navigation drawer with a web view, where each different fragment loads a different URL so i made the following:

Array.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="nav_options">
        <item>Woffer</item>
        <item>Quiero Ofertas!</item>
        <item>Inscribir mi local</item>
        <item>Consultas</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="webs">
        <item>http://woffer.com.ar</item>
        <item>http://woffer.com.ar</item>
        <item>http://woffer.com.ar/inscribir</item>
        <item>http://woffer.com.ar/contacto</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>

Fragment java:

    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public final static String KEY_TEXT = "key_text";

    private String mText;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    WebView mWebView;
    private ViewPager ViewPager;
    View rootview;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false);
        ViewPager = (ViewPager) rootview.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mWebView = (WebView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String[] yourstring = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.webs);
        mWebView.loadUrl(yourstring[ViewPager.getCurrentItem()]); //I don't know how to get the "index" of the current fragment for the url array
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return rootview;
    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {  
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return (false);
        }
    }

}
```

So basically i anyone can help me on what to put on the url array so it matches the current fragment

Thanks!

Comment: When you click on the Navigation Drawer item, put the position inside of a Bundle and pass it to your fragment. Then inside your fragment, use that bundle to get the position or index.

Comment: why dont you use just one fragment with webview and change the url on the webview. you can enable history on the webview to navigate back with back button